# How do rabbis explain the reason for the Spanish Expulsion. Why did the Jewish people deserve it

Tags: history, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, reward-punishment, anti-semitism

I notice you already have [this question for the Holocaust](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8855) but haven't found it for the Spanish expulsion. I understand that many great people gave reasons for it, like the seder hadoros, tsror hamor and ohr hachaim of yosef yaavets linked below. Perhaps you know of many others. Why did the Jewish people deserve the Expulsion?

[here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45329&st=&pgnum=4) six lines from the bottom. 
[here](http://www.ismachmoshe.com/%D7%91%D7%94%D7%A8-%D7%91%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%AA%D7%99.htm)  And 
[here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46817&st=&pgnum=253)

Comment: I believe the primary reason was antisemitism. Could be wrong tho...

Comment: My question was more to do with why the Jewish people deserved it. Shall change it.

Comment: @shulem who says they deserved it?

Comment: Is this the same as [why do bad things happen to good people](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/863/472), or is there something specific about the inquisition?

Comment: http://www.ismachmoshe.com/%D7%91%D7%94%D7%A8-%D7%91%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%AA%D7%99.htmכך כותב רבי אברהם סבע, ממגורשי ספרד שהגיעו לפאס, בספרו צרור המור (פרשת פקודי ופרשת בהר) שאחד הטעמים לגירוש ספרד משום שהיו יוצאים בזמן קריאת התורה מבית הכנסת לדבר שיחה בטלה, והיו עושים מריבות, מחלוקות וקטטות בבית הכנסת בשבתות וימים טובים, וכל זה לפי שלא הייתה להם יראת בית הכנסת, ומשום כך נאמר ”את שבתותי תשמרו ומקדשי תיראו אני ה‘“, להזהיר על מורא בית הכנסת בפרט ביום השבת.

Comment: The three seforim I have so far mentioned all say they deserved it but for different reasons.

Comment: The seder hadoros gives the reason, I cant find it at the moment, that the Jewish people were rich and had non Jewish maidservants from whom they had children who afterwards grew up to be the monks and priests who killed them.

Comment: @MonicaCellio We tend to special-case national tragedies - the Churbans (I and II), various exiles, and the Holocaust come to mind.  In each case, there are many who introspect and think how we (as a nation) failed.

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45329&st=&pgnum=4  six lines from the bottom.

Comment: Shulem, we may need to change the language of this question. Are you referring to the forced conversion of Spanish Jews and their expulsion, or are you referring to the Spanish inquisition? The two things are different: the purpose of the inquisition was to seek out and find Jews who hadn't really converted and to locate "Judaisers" and burn them. It had nothing to do with forcing their conversion or with exiling them from Spain.

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46817&st=&pgnum=253

Comment: ת
 וארגאון ׳ וקמו על היהודים והרגום והסירו י
 דתם יותר מן מאתים אלף יהודים וסיסי
 השנה אל קנ״א, ואנחנו קבלנו כי ה , י
 לוקחים היהודים באותו זמן גויות ב בתיה״
 ונתעברו וילדו בנים / הם הגרם שהרגו לאבותש
 והשמידום, ובזה השמד באו לאפריקא ר 3 י
 מיימון בר סעדיה נגאר בקוסטנטיגא ור׳יצח-ז

Comment: @ShimonbM, better now?

Comment: @MonicaCellio: http://youtu.be/ENOL1RJ1u4s ?

Comment: The same question can be asked Why did the Jews deserve to have Rabbi Akiva burned alive in Rome on the stake limb by limb, with flesh being torn from his body... why?

Comment: I believe that question, in particular, has indeed been asked.

Comment: גזרה היא מלפני.

Comment: I gave 3 answers I was asking if anyone knew anymore.

Answer (score 6):

We are told many times throughout the Torah and Tanach that we will be spread to the four corners of the Earth among the nations and that....

> וּבַגּוֹיִם הָהֵם לֹא תַרְגִּיעַ, וְלֹא-יִהְיֶה מָנוֹחַ
>   לְכַף-רַגְלֶךָ; וְנָתַן יְהוָה לְךָ שָׁם לֵב רַגָּז, וְכִלְיוֹן
>   עֵינַיִם וְדַאֲבוֹן נָפֶשׁ.
>
> And among these nations shalt thou have no repose, and there shall be
>   no rest for the sole of thy foot; but the LORD shall give thee there a
>   trembling heart, and failing of eyes, and languishing of soul ([Dvarim 28:65](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9992/jewish/Chapter-28.htm#v65))

All are troubles throughout history are pointed to from this pasuk... We, as a nation, will never have long lasting peace and security living among the nations.... this is all to remind us that we don't belong there and it is not our destiny to remain in galus.

Comment: I gave 3 answers from rabbonim living at the time or near it. My question was if anybody knew of anymore.

Comment: Well if that is not prophecy fulfilled then i don't know what is.