# Innocent babies killed in flood

Tags: death, sin, parashat-noach, baby-infant, mabul

In Parasha Noach, why were presumably innocent babies killed in the Flood?
I would appreciate if someone could provide some elucidation.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/863/bad-things-happening-to-good-people/25575#25575

Comment: @Sta:  Welcome to Mi Yodeya.  You ask a good question, but it is similar to the broader question of why do bad things happen to children today?  Therefore, your question is duplicative to the question Gershon Gold links to in his comment. You might want to read Rabbi Benjamin Blech's book, "If God Is Good, Why Is The World So Bad?" There he challenges the belief that an all-powerful G-d and bad things happening to people are mutually exclusive ideas.

Comment: Maybe there were no babies at the time of the flood due to infertility. Maybe there is some midrash on this.

Comment: @sta welcome to Mi Yodeya.  If you could [edit] the question to indicate that you are looking for flood-specific explanations (like maybe there's midrash) and not the broader question, that would help to focus answers (and prevent it from being treated as a dupe).  Thanks.

Comment: perhaps they were being paid back from a past gilgul.

Answer (score 3):

Ohr Hachayim Noach 6,10 and 7,1 discusses this. It appears that minors can pass on due to parental sins. it was only because of Noach's righteousness that they were saved in his merit (as minors). It is unclear if this is the case only with bnai-Noach or also with Yisroel. Later, he indicates that Noach's children were saved because in Noach's merit they were judged as k'tanei Yisroel who merit olam haba, as opposed to k'tanei b'nai Noach. This appears to be another angle and not the same as the aforementioned.

Comment: Noach's kids were about 100 years old at the time (and married) so counting them as minors/babies seems a little off.