# Why does God allow a person to experience great suffering at an old age

Tags: choleh-sick

I have watched elderly people with disease, suffering and experiencing moments of despair like Job did, eager to die because life has lost all it meaning to them. There is no longer any joy, or delight, only suffering, discomfort and pain. Yet the end is nowhere in sight. Sleep doesn't give them rest, food doesn't give them nourishment anymore. Day after day is spent sitting in a chair or in bed, not able to do anything just waiting for the day to pass. Is there an answer in Scripture for why God allows this to continue?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/863

Comment: So they can do teshuva. It's in Sanhedrin. Happy to write an answer if I find time

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/863

Comment: Well thought out answer in this post. I have not thought about it before as the author of that post puts it.